# A question on modules over Noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $G$ is a module over the non-trivial commutative Noetherian ring $R$ then is it possible that for all maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ we have $MG=G$ ?

I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I assume you also want the assumption that $G\neq 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the answer is yes: 
$R=\mathbb Z, G=\mathbb Q$ .